# When can you specialize a template on a private member type?

Tags: c++, templates

Given these definitions

```
template<class T> class foo {};
template<class T> class foo1 { static int i; };
class bar { class baz {}; };
```

I'm surprised to see that this compiles

```
template<>
class foo<bar::baz> {};
```

but this fails with the error `'class bar::baz' is private`

```
template<>
int foo1<bar::baz>::i = 42;
```

When does this happen, and is there a workaround other than making the type public?

Comment: That *is* interesting. I'm getting that it's an error defining a variable of this class. I.e., `foo<bar::baz>{};` is OK (g++), but then `foo<bar::baz> f;` is not. So it's pretty much an unusable type, and it looks like the error just comes relatively late (i.e., not at class definition).

Comment: @AmiTavory It's not unusable, as you can always add a [public type alias](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22807544d8414c4e). Interesting question, though. Why is there an access check on the specialization for `::i`?

Comment: @DanielFrey My understanding is that the question is about the case without modifying the code of `bar`.

Comment: @AmiTavory My point was just that the specialization is accepted on the private type, only the use requires the public alias (which is IMHO quite reasonable as the author of `bar` might want to specialize some other template `foo` for his own private type `baz`). But yes, the question is about the specialization for `::i`, so that doesn't help much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider [**CWG #182**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#182):

> Certain access checks are suppressed on explicit instantiations.
>   14.7.2 [temp.explicit] paragraph 8 says […] I was surprised that similar wording does not exist (that I could find) for explicit
>   specializations. I believe that the two cases should be handled
>   equivalently in the example below (i.e., that the specialization
>   should be permitted).
>
> ```
> template <class T> struct C {
>   void f();
>   void g();
> };
>
> template <class T> void C<T>::f(){}
> template <class T> void C<T>::g(){}
>
> class A {
>   class B {};
>   void f();
> };
>
> template void C<A::B>::f();    // okay
> template <> void C<A::B>::g(); // error - A::B inaccessible
> ```
>
> […]
>
> **Rationale (October 2002)**:
>
> **We reconsidered this and decided that the difference between the two
>   cases (explicit specialization and explicit instantiation) is
>   appropriate. The access rules are sometimes bent when necessary to
>   allow naming something, as in an explicit instantiation, but explicit
>   specialization requires not only naming the entity but also providing
>   a definition somewhere.**

GCC and Clang do indeed reject the last line of the example shown, which is - apparently - inconsistent behavior, as for a corresponding explicit specialization of a class template, they do not issue an error message:

```
template <class> struct T {
    void g();
};

class A { class B; class C; };

template <> struct T<A::B>;    // Ok
template <> void T<A::C>::g(); // Error
```

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/683d27c05be058e8). So I'll go out on a limb here and call both cases you showed ill-formed by §14.3/3:

> The name of a *template-argument* shall be accessible at the point
>   where it is used as a *template-argument*.