# Can template specializations take private fields & functions as parameters?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

When I try to compile this code

```
template<class T, T>
struct S;

class C
{
    int x;
    void f();
};

template<>
struct S<int C::*, &C::x> { };

template<>
struct S<void (C::*)(), &C::f> { };

void C::f()
{
    S<int C::*, &C::x> s1;
    S<void (C::*)(), &C::f> s2;
}

int main()
{
}
```

[Clang and GCC compile it fine, but MSVC errors on `&C::f`](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1MoGMYqbs):

```
error C2248: 'C::f': cannot access private member declared in class 'C'
```

This is kind of bizarre to me, as there is no error on `x`, only `f`.

Is MSVC correct here, or is this code legal?

Comment: May https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31033068/when-can-you-specialize-a-template-on-a-private-member-type help you?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: I'm not sure. Is the text there normative, or is it just talking about their "proposed" clarification? Moreover, Clang accepts both... not sure.

Comment: Looks like it was legalized in C++20 https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/temp.spec.general#6 by [P0692R1](http://wg21.link/P0692R1)

Comment: @LanguageLawyer: Wow, thanks. Looks like you're referring to [this](/q/64960135)? And sounds like MSVC is buggy here? Would you like to post an answer so I can accept it? (Note that my question wasn't specific to C++20, so you could explain that it was previously illegal.)

Comment: _Would you like to post an answer_ No.